# Three.js - Rotating a object around certain axis

Tags: three.js

I've used THREE={REVISION:"68"}

I've already done rotation (OBJECT_X) by axis `"z"`http://jsfiddle.net/eVkgs/39/

When I change position OBJECT_X: `CubeGeometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 20,Cube_height/2, 0 ) );` http://jsfiddle.net/eVkgs/40/

Object is still rotate by axis "z" becouse I setup : `OBJECT_X.rotation.z += 0.3*Math.PI/30;`

**Question** : how should look code that allow to rotate around axis which this object is placed ?

Comment: Is http://jsfiddle.net/eVkgs/41/ what you want?

Comment: Put the answer in the answer section, not in the question. You can then accept your own answer by clicking on the green checkmark.

Comment: Well, answer is yours, not mine. I just want to make order, maybe someone will have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object will rotate around its origin in its local coordinate system. If you want to shift the origin, then you have to translate the geometry itself. Here is the pattern to follow:

```
geometry.translate( dx, dy, dz );
```

You can now create a mesh from the geometry, and set the mesh position:

```
mesh.position.set( x, y, z );
```

If you rotate the mesh, it will rotate around its new origin, and the mesh will be located at the point ( x, y, z ).

three.js r.84

Comment: How would you do this temporarily.  For example I want an object to rotate on it's local center, but based on a boolean, rotate on another object's center?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem this way

I created the ObjectControls module for ThreeJS that allows you to rotate a single OBJECT (or a Group), and not the SCENE

Include the libary:

then

var controls = new THREE.ObjectControls(camera, renderer.domElement, yourMesh);

You can find here a live demo here: https://albertopiras.github.io/threeJS-object-controls/

Here is the repo: https://github.com/albertopiras/threeJS-object-controls.

I hope this helps