# Rotation round any center in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Rotation happens round the center of a body. Thus both bodies of the end move:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 10, 10, 200, 24 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff } );

gunTrunk = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( gunTrunk );

gunTrunk.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;
gunTrunk.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );

direction = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ).normalize();
gunTrunk.rotateOnAxis( direction, Math.PI / 3 );
```

I would like that one of the ends remained motionless.

Whether there is an easy and effective way of rotation of a body round any axis in any point?
[image]

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "Thus both bodies of the end move". Can you show an example of what's going wrong?

Comment: I need here such [effect](http://neftek.legko.ufanet.ru/MyWebGL/example_rotate_quaternion/)

Comment: @AlmazVildanov In your demo, does this work for you? `gunTrunk.position.set( -100, 0, 0 ); mesh.position.set( -60, 0, 0 );`

Comment: Yes, works. But I look for the decision without object3D. I simply used object3D for demonstration.

Comment: It would be desirable to know the decision through a quaternion

Comment: For another solution see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287238/three-js-rotating-a-object-around-certain-axis#comment41246660_26287238

Comment: Well, I will explore both methods . Later I will write.