# How to rotate around a point of a solid different from origin

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want simply rotate an object around a point different from the origin but still belonging to the solid. How can i do it?

```
var geometryWing = new THREE.SphereGeometry( wingradius, 32, 50 );
geometryWing.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 1.0, 2.0, 0.2 )  );
wingDx = new THREE.Mesh( geometryWing, materialpapp );

wingDx.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
scene.add(wingDx);

wingDx.rotation.x+=0.05;
```

If i use the simple rotation, this is applied around the origin, and with the pivot i need another solid. 
Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287238/three-js-rotating-a-object-around-certain-axis/26289019#26289019

Comment: Thanks, it worked! ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three.js - Rotating a object around certain axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287238/three-js-rotating-a-object-around-certain-axis)